# Search API Solr fulltext search improve results

Tags: search

I use Search_api_solr module with drupal. I have a node with "Sony W800a TV" when I search w800 there is no result but when I search w800a I see this node in results.

How Can I Fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to enable 'partial word' search which would allow for matching w800 with w800a. As described in this [blog post](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/apache-solr-configuring-partial-word-search-functionality/2012-12-12), Apache Solr has this capacity built in, it just needs to be enabled by adding this line to the Solr Schema that comes with Search API

```
<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" mingramsize="3" maxgramsize="25"/>
```

However, pay attention to their caution about performance issues - you want to only enable this capability on a limited field (ex. the title field) rather than a longtext field as it will greatly increase the size of your index and reduce performance.